# Disable (not hide) browser scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a popup lightbox that needs to be opened in a page using javascript. When opening the popup I need to disable the scrollbar of the browser but it should be visible. I tried the following code

```
$('body').css({'position' : 'fixed' ,'overflow-y':'scroll','width':'100%'});
```

This code will disable the scroller but it make the page jumps to the top as the popup is opening at the vertical centre of the page, which is a serious UI issue.

Also fixed may not work in IE6

Answer (score -1):

You can use some mask kind of effect with transparency, so that if the popup comes the browser is disabled and the user cannot do any actions on that.

Comment: Thanks Mohan, But masking can be applied only for the tags coming inside body right, I need to mask the browser scrolling itself